# When to use Navigator or Package Explorer view?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have imported an existing project built using Maven into my Eclipse workspace. Should we use Navigator or Package Explorer to view our projects in Eclipse?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try both and look at the differences. You'll notice that the Navigator is presented like as a disk file system folder structure (like Windows Explorer) and that the Package Explorer groups the Java classes in packages instead of a bunch of folder trees.

Which one to choose is purely a matter of taste and usefulness of the view. When developing in Java, the Package Explorer is more handy. When just scanning for loose files, the Navigator may be more handy. Each has also its own (configureable) set of filters to hide certain types of files. You'll by default not see `.class` files in Package Explorer, but you can see them in Navigator (in the `/bin` folder).

Comment: Thank you very much Saket and BalusC , as just now i imported the Existing project into Eclipse , i like this Navigator view for now . Anyway thank you very much  .

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that you won't end up fiddling too much with creating packages when using Navigator view. It's impractical to view/group packages in a sensible manner (hey, that's why *Package Explorer* is called exactly like that ;) )

Answer (score 2):

The **Navigator** is more of a hierarchical file explorer, to explore all artifacts within the project, while the **Package Explorer** provides a Java package view.

So, when you are looking to view/edit code, you would rather use the **Package Explorer**, while use the **Navigator** when browsing project artifacts.